# getting error when adding my site url to google webmaster tool

Tags: c#, gdata, google-search-console

i am using this code and every time i am getting error in c#

```
Google.GData.Client.RequestSettings settings = new Google.GData.Client.RequestSettings("ProjektName", "E-MAIL", "PWD"); 
Google.WebmasterTools.WebmasterToolsRequest f = new Google.WebmasterTools.WebmasterToolsRequest(settings);
```

> GDataRequestException, Execution of authentication request returned unexpected result: 404

For adding site

```
Google.GData.Client.RequestSettings settings = new Google.GData.Client.RequestSettings("ProjektName", "E-MAIL", "PWD"); 
Google.WebmasterTools.WebmasterToolsRequest f = new Google.WebmasterTools.WebmasterToolsRequest(settings); 

Google.WebmasterTools.Sites site = new Google.WebmasterTools.Sites(); 
site.AtomEntry = new Google.GData.Client.AtomEntry(); 
site.AtomEntry.Content.Src = "http://www.example.com/"; 
site.AtomEntry.Content.Type = "text/plain"; 
Google.WebmasterTools.Sites newSite = f.AddSite(site);
```

For adding sitemap

```
Google.WebmasterTools.Sitemap sitemap = new Google.WebmasterTools.Sitemap(); 
sitemap.Id = "http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml"; 
sitemap.Categories.Add(new Google.GData.Client.AtomCategory("http://schemas.google.com/webmasters/tools/2007#site-info", new Google.GData.Client.AtomUri("http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"))); 
sitemap.SitemapType = "WEB"; 
Google.WebmasterTools.Sitemap newSitemap = f.AddSitemap("http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Eexample%2Ecom%2F", sitemap);
```

can anybody please help me

Answer (score 0):

The GData API was deprecated a few months ago, you'll need to switch to the Oauth2 based API:
See more at https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/ and the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/webmasters/v3/).

To get a list of sites with Python with the new API (we don't have C# examples, but this can give you a good idea):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import httplib2

from apiclient import errors
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow


# Copy your credentials from the console
CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET'

# Check https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/ for all available scopes
OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly'

# Redirect URI for installed apps
REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'

# Run through the OAuth flow and retrieve credentials
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI)
authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
print 'Go to the following link in your browser: ' + authorize_url
code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ').strip()
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)

# Create an httplib2.Http object and authorize it with our credentials
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

webmasters_service = build('webmasters', 'v3', http=http)

# Retrieve list of websites in account
site_list = webmasters_service.sites().list().execute()

# Remove all unverified sites
verified_sites_urls = [s['siteUrl'] for s in site_list['siteEntry'] if s['permissionLevel'] != 'siteUnverifiedUser']

# Printing the urls of all sites you are verified for.
for site_url in verified_sites_urls:
  print site_url
  # Retrieve list of sitemaps submitted
  sitemaps = webmasters_service.sitemaps().list(siteUrl=site_url).execute()
  if 'sitemap' in sitemaps:
    sitemap_urls = [s['path'] for s in sitemaps['sitemap']]
    print "  " + "\n  ".join(sitemap_urls)
```